# How can I pass information between storyboard scenes using segues?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I followed tutorial for creating 2 storyboard scenes [Tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboarding_%28iOS_6%29#Creating_the_Storyboard_Example_Project) and I know how to pass information from scene 1 to scene 2 using code bellow:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    Scene2ViewController *destination = 
                  [segue destinationViewController];

    destination.labelText = @"Arrived from Scene 1";
}
```

However am I unclear on how to return information from scene 2 (send Boolean value) as tutorial is using unwinding to avoid creating new instance of scene1 and I cannot use method on scene1 below to assign anything from scene2:

```
    -(IBAction)returned:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {

Scene2ViewController *destination = 
                      [segue destinationViewController];
        if (destination.thisIsBooleanFromScene2){
       //do something

   }
    }
```

Comment: Assign the scene 1 viewController as a delegate of scene 2. This is the typical way to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `Scene2ViewController` header, you can put a `@property` of your current view controller so you have acces to its public variables

so in `Scene2ViewController.h`:

```
#import "YourPreviousViewController.h"

//add this to your @interface
@property (strong) YourPreviousViewController *parent;
```

then in your current viewcontroller.m

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
Scene2ViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
destination.parent = self;
}
```

then you can run your `returned` method from `Scene2ViewController` or you can just manipulate the public variables on your current viewcontroller ie `parent`

edit: i have never seen a returned method like that before, you could just make a method that will set the variables you need in your current view controller, then in `Scene2ViewController` you can implement `- (void) viewWillDisappear {  }` which will run  when you press back or segue to another view

```
//Scene2ViewController.m
- (void) viewWillDisappear {  
[self.parent returnAndSetBool:someBool];

//or if myBoolean in the previous view controller is a public variable you can just go:
//self.parent.myBoolen = someBool;
}
```

---

```
//CurrentViewController.m
- (void) returnAndSetBool: (bool) passbackVariable {
self.myBoolean = passbackVariable;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer I do get error for the line:
destination.parent = self;

Incompatible pointer type assigning to 'UISplitViewController' from  Scene1ViewController *const_strong

Comment: Never mind figured how to access property on scene 1, I declared it by mistake as private property.